# How to access a Variable value from a class in java

Tags: java, mysql, variables

I am trying to Show UserName in my MainDashboard.
i am retriving it in methods class and storing the userName in a Variable and accessing that Variable from Dashboard but all i am receiving is nothing 
my Dashboard Code is

```
         String Query="SELECT `FirstName` FROM `localuserregisteratin` WHERE 
           `Email`='"+a.Email+"' AND  `Password`='"+a.Password+"' ";
            Statement stmtt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rst=stmtt.executeQuery(Query);

            while (rst.next()) {           
               PartnerFirstName=rst.getString("Firstname");
               frmLocalUser frm=new frmLocalUser();
               frm.UserFirstName=PartnerFirstName;
            }
```

and my dashboard form code is

```
              txtUserName.setText(this.m.PartnerFirstName);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Your code will fail as soon as there is a quote in one of the arguments, and is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Also forget about backticks and case sensitive table and column names. And respect the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Use getter/ setter to access variables. Like getPartnerFirstName().
 And also in this case you can return your value.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks on column names should be avoided. They are not ANSI-SQL compliant, means it won't work when the same query gonna run with sql server. I suspect there is a typo in localuserregisteratin, that's why you are not getting any data out of the table. To access data member from a class, getter is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

`txtUserName.setText(this.m.UserFirstName);` or `txtUserName.setText(this.UserFirstName);`

will help if `m` object is mapped to `frm`
 If you are assigning to `UserFirstName` of `frm` object you should retrieve 
that parameter(**`UserFirstName`**) only.
Best Practice would be using Getter and Setters while assigning and accessing the states of an object in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above answers should guide you through, however i just added the code snippet for you to be familiar with.

This call be your class with prepared statements to get data from DB

```
/* Class #1 */
public class VariableWriteClass {
    public VariableClass methodWriteClass(){
        VariableClass vClass = new VariableClass();
        vClass.setUserName("bob");
        return vClass;
    }
}
```

Getter and Setter

```
/* POJO class*/
public class VariableClass {
    String userName;
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

This can be your MainDashboard class

```
/* Class #2 */
public class VariableAccessClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        callMethod();
    }
    private static void callMethod() {
        VariableWriteClass vWrite = new VariableWriteClass();
        VariableClass name = vWrite.methodWriteClass();
        System.out.println(" main class "+name.getUserName());      
    }
}
```